# matlabにて，あるディレクトリ内のIDをひとつずつ読み込みたいのですが，filesep IDという部分が回らず，また何をしているのかわかりません

Tags: matlab

matlab初学者です。他の方が作成されたコードを読しながら自分のPCで回るよう，ディレクトリ参照の部分を変えることを要求されています。
あるディレクトリ内のフォルダをひとつずつ読み込みたいです。フォルダ名はデータIDになっており，IDは「W01_d1」のような「W」「01―16」「d1 or d3」で構成されています。
このIDフォルダの中には「condition1」というフォルダがあり，ソフトウェアで読み込む用のファイルが入っています。

```
maindir = ['E:\HDD' filesep ID];
spmdir_tmp = which('software');
spmdir = spmdir_tmp(1:end-5);
NBdir = {[maindir, '\conditon1' ]};
```

1行目，filesepについて，ヘルプを見ながら「現在のプラットフォームのファイル区切り文字 (≒IDのW01の部分?)」に該当するのかなと理解していますが，実際にIDのフォルダを読み込みませんし，具体的にどこまでこのコードで参照しているのかわかっていません。
IDのフォルダ名を読み込んでいないことは，ソースを回すと，「E:\HDD\condition1」がアウトプットされることで判断しています。

お気づきの点教えて頂けましたら幸いです。宜しくお願い致します。

Comment: `ID`という変数が、最初にいきなり出てきますが、提示のコードより前で値が代入されているのでしょうか。

Comment: ご返信有難うございます。いいえ、提示のコードが一行目です。

Comment: `ID`は変数なので使う前に値が入っていないと実行時にエラーになるはずです。コードを実行する前に、すでに代入されているのでしょうか。

Comment: 他の方が書かれた同じ目的の別コードも見ましたが，Matlabの特徴なのか，変数に値を入れずに書かれていました。ちょっとどういうことなのか私にはわからないので，とりあえず変数の中身を補足したコードを書いています…

Answer (score 0):

MATLABのスクリプトは、ワークスペースにある変数(ほかの言語でいうグローバル変数のようなもの)を自由に参照することができます。例えば、以下のような`setNBdir.m`というスクリプトがあったとします。

```
% setNBdir.m
NBdir = ['test' filesep ID];
```

コマンドウィンドウで、まず`ID`に値を代入してから、このスクリプトを呼び出せば`NBdir`という変数をワークスペースに作ることができます。

```
>> ID = 'hoge';
>> setNBdir
>> NBdir
NBdir =
    'test\hoge'
```

また、別のスクリプトから呼び出すこともできます。

```
% callNBdir.m
IDs = {'A', 'BB', 'CCC'};
for i = 1:numel(IDs)
    ID = IDs{i};
    setNBdir
    disp(NBdir)
end
```

このスクリプト(callNBdir.m)を実行すると

```
>> callNBdir
test\A
test\BB
test\CCC
```

という結果が得られます。

もしスクリプトの中で`ID`という変数を定義もせずに使っているのなら、あらかじめ`ID`を用意してあることが前提のスクリプトなのでしょう(もし、他の人にも使ってもらうためのスクリプトなら、ワークスペースを使わずに済む関数を作った方がいいですが)。

結論としては「`ID`の中身は自分で用意しましょう」です。